# convert time to arab timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime

I got a working example for converting time to other timezones, but no arab

Tried many ways, but always got "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-03-21 14:35:43" (at offset 5)"

what im doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
      public String convertTime(String inputTime) {
    try {

        //first block, that works
        /*SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date parsed = sourceFormat.parse(inputTime); // => Date is in UTC now

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

        return destFormat.format(parsed);*/

        //another effort, not working 
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
        Date myDate = df.parse(inputTime);
        String testTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate);
        return testTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "61:61";
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateFormat.SHORT` read the doc for that

Comment: The commented-out code works nicely on my computer, converts `2017-03-21 14:35:43` to the corresponding time in the computer’s time zone (haven’t tried setting the computer’s time zone to Arab, though).

Comment: Whan you say Arab time zone, do you mean for instance Riyadh (Arabia Standard Time/Arabia Daylight Time)? Or maybe your computer’s time zone setting will be good enough, whatever that is?

Comment: i tried to fake Arab timezone by using virtual android phone with Arab lang settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you do wrong? First, your commented-out code works nicely on my computer, I see nothing really wrong with that. It converts the input string `2017-03-21 14:35:43` from your question to the corresponding time in the computer’s time zone.

Your “another effort, not working”, you are relying on a locale-dependent format. This is dangerous with a lenient class like `DateFormat`. You have every chance that something will go wrong without the date format telling you so. On my computer, your code gives `07-09-2026`, which means 7 September 2026 and obviously is wrong. Adding a `Locale` argument may be an improvement, for example: `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ROOT)`. Now I get `Unparseable date: "2017-03-21 14:35:43"`. This format would have expected the input as `3/21/2017 2:35 PM` (with no seconds). At least it now tells us it doesn’t work. I think a similar format is expected if your computer is set to some Arabic locale. Try for example `System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));` to find out.

That said, if you can, you can do yourself a favour by skipping the old classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, `Date` and `DateFormat`. The date and time classes introduced in Java 8 are better designed, nicer and more convenient to work with and in many cases better suited for whatever we want to use them for. I would write:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public static String convertTime(String inputTime) {
    ZoneId destinationTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Riyadh");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(inputTime, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(destinationTimeZone)
            .format(formatter);
}
```

Using your input string `2017-03-21 14:35:43` this yields `2017-03-21 17:35:43`. Please insert your desired time zone in the first line in the method. If for example you want to use the computer’s time zone setting, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

How it works? The method parses the input, interprets it in UTC, finds the corresponding time in the Arab time zone and formats it back using the same format.

`LocalDateTime.parse()` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` if the input string cannot be parsed, so you may want to catch this and act accordingly. Don’t just catch `Exception`, it’s bad practice and will leave you with no knowledge about what went wrong.

Comment: No need to go through `ZoneOffset.UTC` and an `OffsetDateTime` in your example code. Go directly to `ZonedDateTime` by calling [`LocalDateTime::atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-), as in `LocalDateTime.parse(inputTime, formatter).atZone( z )`

Comment: That doesn’t give the same result, @BasilBourque. I get `2017-03-21 14:35:43`, the same as the input. When converting from UTC, we need to somehow tell which offset we want to convert from.

Comment: I retract my suggestion. Your code was correct as it was. I misunderstood in thinking that `Asia/Riyadh` was the intended zone. On rereading the Question I see UTC was intended as the primary zone, and Riyadh was secondary.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 public static String dateFormatter(Date postDate){

    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    { format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+5"));}
    String date = format.format(postDate);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the milliseconds

Comment: @cricket_007 doesn't seem to be any ms in the OP's input

Comment: @njzk2 hm? 2017-03-21 14:35:43

Comment: @cricket_007 yes? as you can see, there is no ms in this input, so I don't get how iravul is missing them.

Comment: @njzk2 oops. Seconds... It's early here

Comment: You probably mean `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch especially, i did not care about that. but thank you for feedback and i edited.

Comment: You probably meant `GMT+5`? (or +3 or +4?)

Comment: @OleV.V. i am not sure what Vadim needs

Comment: Neither am I, @iravul, certainly not. I just meant to say `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTM+5")` is incorrect anyway. It gives you GMT, this is what `getTimeZone()` gives you when it doesn’t recognize the time zone ID string you pass to it. You are right, of course, the original asker should just fill in a valid ID for his/her desired time zone.